# DXL: Copy Objects from one closed module to a second closed module

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm trying to create a DXL script that will take all the objects from select set of modules and combine them into a new module which will then be exported to Excel.

The issue I'm having is I can't figure out how to get objects from a module that isn't open. I'm open to any method but I've been trying to use ModuleHandles. Most of the examples I've seen are for moving objects within the current module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two variables of type Module, one for the source module (e.g. mSrc), one for the target module (mTgt). Use the command `read` for opening the source module and setting the resulting handle to mSrc. Use `edit` (or  `create`) for opening the target module and setting the resulting handle to mTgt.

Then use a variable of type Object for iterating over all objects of mSrc (`for oSrc in mSrc` or perhaps `... in entire mSrc`, depending on how the views in your source modules are set up), create objects in the target module (to a variable oTgt of type Object) copy the object attributes that you need from oSrc to oTgt. For the latter there is a function copyAttribute_ in copyops.inc.

If you want to replicate the hierarchy of the source module, you will need loops of type `for Object in Object` and commands like `create after` `create below` etc. 
Perhaps there are already scripts available in IBMs DXL Forum or on some of the web sites that provide a solution for your problem.